# Using Hibernate with OSGi and Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to add Hibernate as a dependency of my OSGi bundle using Maven. In my POM file I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I ran that I got an error:

*org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.hibernate.core [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction.xa)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 15.0: missing requirement [15.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.enterprise.context)]*

So I added another dependency for javax.enterprise.context:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Which solved the previous error but lead to another error:

*Auto-properties install: file:///path/to/project/hibernate/target/bundles/javax.inject-1.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object. - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException)*

And now, I am unable to solve this one or even find out what causes it. I use Apache Felix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work. If you want to use Hibernate in OSGi you'll need some bundle that actually provide the needed interfaces in osgi bundles. 
For your current use-case I'd suggest using Karaf and install the JPA/JTA features of Apache Aries. 
Karaf is a OSGi container with lots of dependencies resolved and easy to install features. 
To use Karaf with JPA just do the following

```
features:install jpa
features:install jta
features:install hibernate
```

with that you should be set to use hibernate in an osgi container. 
Another approach would be to install all required bundles to run blueprint osgi with hibernate and jpa/jta support yourself. For a list of those take a look at the corresponding features files. Available at [Karaf](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/features/enterprise/3.0.1/enterprise-3.0.1-features.xml)